# Get two numbers by given Ratio

Tags: ratio

How to solve this? with computation.
At Sports Store, there were $380$ Basketballs and $263$ Baseballs. When an equal number of Basketballs and Baseballs were sold, the ratio of remaining Basketballs to remaining Baseballs became $8:5$. How many basketballs were sold?

Comment: Let $x$ be the number of basketballs sold. Using the unknown $x$, can you set up an equation of the form
$$\text{some expression} = \frac{8}{5}$$
??

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be the number of basketballs and baseballs are sold.

Then remaining,

Basketballs $= 380 - x$

Baseballs $= 263 - x$

Now ratio,

$\frac{380 - x}{263 - x} = \frac 85$

$5 \cdot (380 - x) = 8 \cdot (263 - x)$

$1900 - 5x = 2104 - 8x$

$8x - 5x = 2104 - 1900$

$3x = 204$

$x = \frac{204}3$

$x = 68$

Answer (score 0):

Let the number of balls sold be $x$ then according to question: $$\frac{380-x}{263-x}=\frac{8}{5}$$ after solving this you will get $$x=68$$